# Wrapping shortcode content in a span or link

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, links

My shortcode includes a **switch statement**, that outputs a one-word weather summary. This displays correctly when I swap `$summary =` for `return`, but I cannot seem to get it working with a `<span>` or link around the content.

What am I missing here?

```
switch ( $weather['icon'] ) {

    case 'clear-day': case 'clear-night': 
        $summary = 'sunny'; 
        break;
    case 'wind': 
        $summary = 'breezy'; 
        break;
    case 'rain': 
        $summary = 'drizzly'; 
        break;              
    case 'fog': 
        $summary = 'foggy'; 
        break;
    case 'cloudy': 
        $summary = 'murky'; 
        break;
    case 'partly-cloudy-day': case 'partly-cloudy-night': 
        $summary = 'cloudy'; 
        break;
    case 'snow': case 'sleet':
        $summary = 'snowy'; 
        break;
    default: 
        $summary = 'beautiful'; 
        break;

    return '<span class="weather">'.$summary.'</span>';

} // end switch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get out of the `switch` block before placing the final `return` statement.

> if you place `return` at the end of the `switch` block that way, the `switch` block already ends before it gets to the `return` statement (because of the previous matching `break` statements).

The correct CODE will be:

```
// just in case $summary is not defined out side of the switch block
$summary = '';
switch ( $weather['icon'] ) {

    case 'clear-day':
    case 'clear-night': 
        $summary = 'sunny'; 
        break;
    case 'wind': 
        $summary = 'breezy'; 
        break;
    case 'rain': 
        $summary = 'drizzly'; 
        break;              
    case 'fog': 
        $summary = 'foggy'; 
        break;
    case 'cloudy': 
        $summary = 'murky'; 
        break;
    case 'partly-cloudy-day': case 'partly-cloudy-night': 
        $summary = 'cloudy'; 
        break;
    case 'snow': case 'sleet':
        $summary = 'snowy'; 
        break;
    default: 
        $summary = 'beautiful'; 
        break;

} // end switch

return '<span class="weather">'.$summary.'</span>';
```